# LPF based Differential demodulator design

Tags: operational-amplifier, cmos, differential, demodulation

I am designing LPF based differential demodulator(LPF_DDM) to retrieve differentially modulated signals, which are on-chip capacitive isolated [shown]. LPF_DDM includes a differential amplifier, LPF, and Schmitt trigger. I designed a two-stage opamp [specification below], as a differential amplifier. Simulation results of the 2-stage opamp matched with desired specifications (GBW, Phase margin, gain, etc ). However when the differential modulated signals are given as input, then opamp does not work.
Is my 2-stage opamp design and/or design parameters adequate for differential modulated input signal?

Thanks.

Design Parameters:
Input common mode range: ICMRmax = 4V; ICMRmin = 1.5V ; Load capacitance =2pF ; Gain = 1000/60db ; Slew-rate (SR) = 20v/usec. GBW=30MHz
Phase margin (PM)>= 60-degree

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Encoded data seems to be order of `10^6 Hz` (us in time axis). LPF cut off seems to be `10^4 Hz`. What is the rationale behind these choices ? What happens if the encoded data was in kHz range? Does it work then?

Comment: I operate the system in KHz but the response is almost the same.

Comment: Moreover, I also added figures to understand the ultimate output.

Comment: There is no bias or signal specs

Comment: circuit shown will not demodulate